# How can I restrict my iframe to only use local content?

Tags: web-application, iframe

How can I restrict my iFrame to use only local (i.e. not from other websites) content?  My question is the reverse of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397267/how-to-deny-site-access-from-an-iframe?noredirect=1&lq=1) as how to restrict other sites from using my site in an iframe.

I am using Tomcat/Java/JSP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set a [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) header with the `child-src` directive.

For example, this will only allow frame content from the same domain:

```
Content-Security-Policy: child-src 'self'
```

Instead of `'self'` you can also specify a particular origin.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/qakaserexa/) is a simple demo (the meta tag is used to simulate the header). Only the first frame should load:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="child-src http://example.com/">
<iframe src="http://example.com/"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://example.org/"></iframe>
```

Note that this works in Firefox and Chrome but [isn't supported in IE](http://caniuse.com/#search=csp) and older browsers.

Comment: Before CSP, this used to done with the header "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN". Can you expect that all browsers support CSP, or should you add this for backwards compatibility?

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld As I understand it, this is precisely what OP does not want. `X-Frame-Options` prevents embedding from the frame's perspective, not from the perspective of the parent.

Comment: Of course, I mixed these things up. Thanks for the clarification @Arminius

Comment: Hi @Arminius - just to add that this solution doesn't work for IE -  see http://caniuse.com/#search=csp Here is a link to test if csp works in one's browser https://content-security-policy.com/browser-test/

Comment: @gordon613 Thanks for catching that, I added a note.